# How can I make my code for User Login Info in a Database?

Tags: vb.net

I am making an application on Visual Basic 2010 using the Language vb.net and am wondering if it is safe to allow the user to create and edit their info into a database so i don't have to do it for every individual myself.

Database Structure (Columns):
id
member
Username
Password
Email

This is just to list all Users Signed Up:

`MySQLCon = New MySqlConnection
    'Replaced info below for security purposes.
MySQLCon.ConnectionString = "Database=localhost;Data Source=sql3.freesqldatabase.com;User Id=user;Password=password"
Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
Dim bSource As New BindingSource
Dim command As MySqlCommand
Try
    MySQLCon.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "SELECT member FROM members"
    command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySQLCon)
    SDA.SelectCommand = command
    SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
    vagueMembers.DataSource = bSource
    SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
    MySQLCon.Close()
    MySQLCon.Dispose()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    'Nothing
End Try`

This is what i use to insert a new member right from the application.

`Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO members(member) VALUES('" & memberToAdd.Text & "')"
submitRequest(SQLStatement)`

I ask again, is it safe to allow a new client to use the 2nd code block to create info?

P.S. This is a (WinForms).

Comment: `INSERT INTO members(member) VALUES('" & memberToAdd...`  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: the second code block isnt safe for *anyone* to use. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: @Plutonix can you put this in an answer according to my code info cause i don't understand it.